TextField cursor in wrong position when placed inside a Popup
When I place my TextField in a Popup, the cursor/caret is not properly aligned to the text anymore:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Popup(
                properties = PopupProperties(
                    focusable = true,
                ),
            ) {
                var textState by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
                TextField(
                    value = textState,
                    onValueChange = { textState = it },
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

The cursor is vertically off-set so it overlays the text itself instead of being placed below it:


I took the liberty to create a [mre] and removed all code that was unnecessary to reproduce the problem. Please verify that this still is what you wanted to ask.

Seems like a bug in Jetpack Compose. I created issue — https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/341432429
